# text file vs database?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am generating millions of lines and store in text files. We generate few millions and store in text file and then repeat this up to a certain number.

I observed saving is taking too much time than generation. We are using following code to save results.

```
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(string.Format("{0}.txt", FILENAME), true))
        {
            for (int i = lastEndIndex; i < storage.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(storage.ElementAt(i));
            }
        }
```

My question is, is there any method to save lines in bulk to text file?

Comment: Define "too much time". How much data writes do you see per second, measured in megabytes? How much do you expect? What data structure is `storage` - does it have constant-time lookup?

Comment: `storage.ElementAt(i)` iterates `storage` `i` times. So what you have here is an algorithm with *O(n²)* complexity. It's not surprising that it doesn't perform well for millions of items.

Comment: You might get better performance writing the bytes manually using a bigger buffer (IIRC the default is roughly 8KB). There's all sorts of environment considerations when you want I/O performance though.. I'd also remove the call to `ElementAt` to increase performance.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead can you provide a link for this?

Comment: @mqpasta No, I can't, but a quick check of the mscorlib assembly shows this in the `StreamWriter` class: `private const int DefaultFileStreamBufferSize = 4096;`. It would appear its closer to 4KB.